# Session flash messages only showing after a separate refresh and not on POST in express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Started with Express a couple weeks ago and finally hit my first roadblock. I'm trying to figure out how to send a flash message to my view (layout.jade). When I'm validating a user signup and it fails validation (using express-validator), I want to write to the session flash message and then show it on the page.

What I'm doing now only works if I refresh AFTER POSTing (e.g. in controllers/index.js), and I also need to figure out how to only make this flash message show once:

/app.js

```
/*
 * Configuration
 */
app.configure(function() {
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(expressValidator);
  app.use(express.cookieParser());
  app.use(express.bodyParser({ uploadDir : './' }));
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(viewHelpers());
  app.use(function(req, res, next){
    res.locals.messages = req.session.messages || {};
    delete req.session.messages;
    next();
  });
  app.use(express.session({
    secret: config.secret,
    cookie: {
      maxAge: 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
    },
    store: new MongoStore(config.db)
  }));
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
  app.use(app.router);
});
```

/views/layout.jade:

```
div.alert.alert-error
  - if (typeof messages !== "undefined")
    !=partial('session_flash', { messages : messages })
```

/views/partials/session_flash.jade:

```
div.alert.alert-error
  each message in messages
    =message
```

/controllers/index.js

```
req.assert(['user', 'username'], 'Please enter a valid username').len(3, 23);
req.assert(['user', 'email'], 'Please enter a valid email').isEmail();
req.assert(['user', 'password'], 'Please enter a valid password').len(3, 23);
req.session.messages = 'Please fix the errors below';
    errors = req.validationErrors();

    if (errors) {
      console.log(errors);
      res.render('join', {
        title : 'Join -',
        errors: errors,
        params: params
      });
      return;
    }
```

Is it only showing up after I refresh (after a POST) because I'm rendering the join template from within `/controllers/index.js` and not `/app.js`? Also, should I be doing something like `delete req.session.messages` within my configuration? I couldn't find a complete example of this anywhere and the ones I've found were outdated.

Comment: Have you looked at connect-flash yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are indeed using an outdated example. Express v3.x doesn't use partials anymore. See [View system changes](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/wiki/Migrating-from-2.x-to-3.x) in the wiki. Instead use [blocks](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#block-append--prepend) and [includes](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade#includes).

An easy way to show error messages on login would be

index.js

```
app.locals.error = null;

app.post('/login', function(req, res){

  var name = req.body.name;
  var password = req.body.password;

  if (!name || !password) {
    res.status(400);
    return res.render('login', {
      error: 'All fields are required'
    });
  }

})
```

`app.locals.error = null` sets the default value of the error to `null`. By doing that you don't have to set the `error` variable every time you render `login.jade` and no `error` is present.

```
res.render('login', {
  error: null
});
```

Your `login.jade` template could look like this

```
extends layout

block content
  - if (error)
    p= error
  form(method='post', action='/login')
    p
      label(for='name') Username:
      input(type='text', name='name', id='name')
    p
      label(for='password') Password:
      input(type='password', name='password', id='password')
    p
      input(type='submit', value='Submit')
```

Comment: Any idea how to get the session message on a redirected page?